# Show representation properties in object inspector in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, representation

When you inspected a feature in the object inspector in ArcMap 9.x (opened by clicking the  "Attributes" button in the editor toolbar), you were able to see the properties of ALL the features representations, as individual tabs in the dialog (behind the attribute tab).

In ArcGIS 10.0, I have not been able to do this. Only, if the representation is active, can I see its properties in the inspector. This has ENORMOUS (!!!) costs to my work.

Until now, my workaround has been to add the layer several times with the different representations, but I am kind of hoping, that there is some way to make. However doing this on a country-wide road network, makes it painstakingly slow to work in ArcMap, so i really hope that one of you has some way of making my problem go away.

Comment: To progress this one I think we will need you to edit in more details of your 10.x workflow and the issue you have with it.